# Getting error javax.sip.PeerUnavailableException: The Peer SIP Stack: gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackImpl could not be instantiated

Tags: java, sip

I am getting error with the following code.

I have included all the jars that are necessary for Sip; but, I am still not getting why this error is occurring. Can you explain this to me?

My code class is:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Properties;

import java.util.Random;


import javax.sip.DialogTerminatedEvent;
import javax.sip.IOExceptionEvent;
import javax.sip.ListeningPoint;
import javax.sip.RequestEvent;
import javax.sip.ResponseEvent;
import javax.sip.SipFactory;
import javax.sip.SipListener;
import javax.sip.SipProvider;
import javax.sip.SipStack;
import javax.sip.TimeoutEvent;
import javax.sip.TransactionTerminatedEvent;
import javax.sip.address.Address;
import javax.sip.address.AddressFactory;
import javax.sip.header.CSeqHeader;
import javax.sip.header.CallIdHeader;
import javax.sip.header.ContactHeader;
import javax.sip.header.FromHeader;
import javax.sip.header.HeaderFactory;
import javax.sip.header.MaxForwardsHeader;
import javax.sip.header.ToHeader;
import javax.sip.header.ViaHeader;
import javax.sip.message.MessageFactory;
import javax.sip.message.Request;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SipClient extends JFrame implements SipListener
{
SipFactory sipFactory;          // Used to access the SIP API.
SipStack sipStack;              // The SIP stack.
SipProvider sipProvider;        // Used to send SIP messages.
MessageFactory messageFactory;  // Used to create SIP message factory.
HeaderFactory headerFactory;    // Used to create SIP headers.
AddressFactory addressFactory;  // Used to create SIP URIs.
ListeningPoint listeningPoint;  // SIP listening IP address/port.
Properties properties;          // Other properties.

String ip;                      // The local IP address.
int port = 6060;                // The local port.
String protocol = "udp";        // The local protocol (UDP).
int tag = (new Random()).nextInt(); // The local tag.
Address contactAddress;         // The contact address.
ContactHeader contactHeader;    // The contact header.
public SipClient() 
{
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the     form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-  BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    buttonRegisterStateless = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonRegisterStatefull = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonInvite = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buttonBye = new javax.swing.JButton();
    textField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("SIP Client");
    setLocationByPlatform(true);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            onOpen(evt);
        }
    });

    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

    buttonRegisterStateless.setText("Reg (SL)");
    buttonRegisterStateless.setEnabled(true);
    buttonRegisterStateless.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            onRegisterStateless(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonRegisterStatefull.setText("Reg (SF)");
    buttonRegisterStatefull.setEnabled(true);
    buttonRegisterStatefull.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            onRegisterStatefull(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonInvite.setText("Invite");
    buttonInvite.setEnabled(true);
    buttonInvite.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            onInvite(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonBye.setText("Bye");
    buttonBye.setEnabled(true);
    buttonBye.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            onBye(evt);
        }
    });

    textField.setText("");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADIN       G)
                .addComponent(scrollPane)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(buttonRegisterStateless, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(buttonRegisterStatefull, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(buttonInvite, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(buttonBye, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 2, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(textField))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(textField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 230, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(buttonRegisterStateless)
                .addComponent(buttonInvite)
                .addComponent(buttonBye)
                .addComponent(buttonRegisterStatefull))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void onOpen(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_onOpen
    try
    {
        this.ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println(ip);
        this.sipFactory=SipFactory.getInstance();
        this.sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");
        this.properties=new Properties();
        this.properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME", "myStack");
        // Create the SIP stack.
        this.sipStack = this.sipFactory.createSipStack(this.properties);
        // Create the SIP message factory.
        this.messageFactory = this.sipFactory.createMessageFactory();
        // Create the SIP header factory.
        this.headerFactory = this.sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();
        // Create the SIP address factory.
        this.addressFactory = this.sipFactory.createAddressFactory();
        // Create the SIP listening point and bind it to the local IP address, port and protocol.
        this.listeningPoint = this.sipStack.createListeningPoint(this.ip, this.port, this.protocol);
        // Create the SIP provider.
        this.sipProvider = this.sipStack.createSipProvider(this.listeningPoint);
        // Add our application as a SIP listener.
        this.sipProvider.addSipListener(this);
        // Create the contact address used for all SIP messages.
        System.out.println("Local address: " + this.ip +" : "+ this.port + "\n");
        this.contactAddress = this.addressFactory.createAddress("sip: "+ this.ip +" : "+ this.port);
        // Create the contact header used for all SIP messages.
        this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory.createContactHeader(contactAddress);

        // Display the local IP address and port in the text area.
        System.out.println("Local address: " + this.ip +" : "+ this.port + "\n");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_onOpen

private void onRegisterStateless(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_onRegisterStateless
    try {
        // Get the destination address from the text field.
        Address addressTo = addressFactory.createAddress(textField.getText());
        // Create the request URI for the SIP message.
        javax.sip.address.URI requestURI = addressTo.getURI();
        // Create the SIP message headers.
        // The "Via" headers.
        ArrayList viaHeaders = new ArrayList();
        ViaHeader viaHeader = headerFactory.createViaHeader(ip, port, "udp", null);
        viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
        // The "Max-Forwards" header.
        MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = headerFactory.createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
        // The "Call-Id" header.
        CallIdHeader callIdHeader = sipProvider.getNewCallId();
        // The "CSeq" header.
        CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(1L,"REGISTER");
        // The "From" header.
        FromHeader fromHeader = headerFactory.createFromHeader(contactAddress, String.valueOf(tag));
        // The "To" header.
        ToHeader toHeader = headerFactory.createToHeader(addressTo, null);

        // Create the REGISTER request.
        Request request = messageFactory.createRequest(
            requestURI,
            "REGISTER",
            callIdHeader,
            cSeqHeader,
            fromHeader,
            toHeader,
            viaHeaders,
            maxForwardsHeader);
        // Add the "Contact" header to the request.
        request.addHeader(contactHeader);

        // Send the request statelessly through the SIP provider.
        sipProvider.sendRequest(request);

        // Display the message in the text area.
      textArea.append(
            "Request sent:\n" + request.toString() + "\n\n");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // If an error occurred, display the error.
        textArea.append("Request sent failed: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_onRegisterStateless

private void onRegisterStatefull(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_onRegisterStatefull
    // A method called when you click on the "Reg (SF)" button.
}//GEN-LAST:event_onRegisterStatefull

private void onInvite(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_onInvite
    // A method called when you click on the "Invite" button.
}//GEN-LAST:event_onInvite

private void onBye(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_onBye
    // A method called when you click on the "Bye" button.
}//GEN-LAST:event_onBye

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SipClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SipClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SipClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SipClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SipClient().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JButton buttonBye;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonInvite;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonRegisterStatefull;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonRegisterStateless;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
private javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
private javax.swing.JTextField textField;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
public void processRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
    // A method called when you receive a SIP request.
}

public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) {
    // A method called when you receive a SIP request.
}

public void processTimeout(TimeoutEvent timeoutEvent) {
    // A method called when a SIP operation times out.
}

public void processIOException(IOExceptionEvent exceptionEvent) {
    // A method called when a SIP operation results in an I/O error.
}

public void processTransactionTerminated(TransactionTerminatedEvent transactionTerminatedEvent) {
    // A method called when a SIP transaction terminates.
}

public void processDialogTerminated(DialogTerminatedEvent dialogTerminatedEvent) {
    // A method called when a SIP dialog terminates.
  }
}
```

I have included the `org.apache.log4j` jar as well but then I am getting the following error nonetheless:

```
javax.sip.PeerUnavailableException: The Peer SIP Stack:   gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackImpl could not be instantiated. Ensure the Path Name has been set.
at javax.sip.SipFactory.createStack(SipFactory.java:324)
at javax.sip.SipFactory.createSipStack(SipFactory.java:152)
at ServerClasses.sc.SipClient.onOpen(SipClient.java:169)
at ServerClasses.sc.SipClient.access$0(SipClient.java:159)
at ServerClasses.sc.SipClient$1.windowOpened(SipClient.java:77)
at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown  Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javax.sip.SipFactory.createStack(SipFactory.java:305)
... 29 more
```

Please help me out with this. I am new With Sip programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need jain-sip-api and jain-sip-ri jars. By looking at the error you are missing the ri jar. You can get the jars from the archive here https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/jain-sip-1.2.2370.tar.gz

Comment: but i have used both the jars

Comment: If you are sure you used both jars then most likely something is wrong with your packaging and you may be having multiple copies of the jar in different classloaders. Are you using some modular framework? If so then dissect your package to make sure both files are in there. Check the classpath. ClassNotFoundException is pretty straightforward in most cases.

Comment: can u provide me a simple sip client program to send request to server and get response back in java

Comment: https://svn.java.net/svn/jsip~svn/trunk/src/examples/simplecallsetup/Shootist.java and see the full client+server example https://svn.java.net/svn/jsip~svn/trunk/src/examples/simplecallsetup

Comment: can we call to any mobile number without register it on sip

Comment: i have this code but not able to ring on any phone i m new in this feild pls help me out

Comment: You can't call numbers out of nowhere. You need to have access to a SIP gateway that will route your calls to actual phones. REGISTER is not always required but authentication is of some sort for sure unless you are a trusted party with a service provider.

Comment: i have an account on voipdiscount.com but not able to make call from my applicaction here